I can play guitar proficiently but I don't "understand" it
I've been playing on and off for a couple of years and I want to write some riffs that don't sound like garbage, but as soon as I start trying to write something in a tuning besides standard it dawns on me how clueless I am.
I'm comfortable with chords and coming up with progressions and stuff but when it comes to riffage and improvisation I just revert to the major or minor scale and I get sick of hearing myself play it because it sounds the same every time, and it's even worse in an alternate tuning when the shapes aren't the same and I sound like it's my first time picking up the instrument.
I guess what I'm asking is: what is the path to true understanding of the instrument? I feel inadequate for the amount of time I've played.
Advice and responses are truly appreciated.

Long answers could be given, but here's a quick tip: Try to separate skills/level from feelings/assessment. Feelings matter too. If you feel bad about yourself, that's something to work on. But feelings have no bearing on your actual skill. If you want to level up your skill, try asking yourself about those skills in ways that are separate from feelings. (And then deal with the feelings separately too.)

As far as riffs and lines, the #1, tried and true method is to copy recordings. Over time, this evolves into creating your own.

Are you assuming that understanding guitar will improve your composing of riffs and songs? I don't personally believe that's true. Regarding your question, are you definitely focused on mastery of the guitar or is your true goal being a better composer?

Have you tried 'noodling'? It's just playing random bits of what you know with other bits you don't know yet - just free play hitting all sorts of notes and intervals and double stops that you did not necessarily mean to play. It gets some bad press because once you start enjoying it you need to discipline yourself and not waste all your time on it, but my understanding is that it gave Keith Richards the Satisfaction riff so it's not a complete waste of time. Scales are not usually your friends when you want to come up with memorable riffs. Try just a few notes, maybe as 4th or 5th intervals.

@Davy5003 - on the contrary, most riffs are made up from parts of scales. The scales themselves will differ, but examine most riffs, and there'll be notes from particular scales.

@Tim Yes of course, any set of notes can be put into some scale or another, but I'd say that most great riffs were not created by thinking 'what can I do with this scale'? They are almost all arrived at by noodling. It's not the notes that you put in but the notes that you leave out which make a great riff, and it's a lot more about timing and articulation than about what scale might eventually fit the notes played.

I don't mean to be too harsh but you remind me myself when I had played guitar for a couple of years. I was practicing probably between 4-8 hours a day and obviously was making quite a progress. I felt very confident about my playing and would describe it as proficient. It took years of further practice, self reflection, recording and most of all playing with other better musicians to realize how much more there is to do to actually become proficient at the instrument. Many really famous guitar players have practiced even 15 hours a day - and that is probably what it takes to be where they are, no shortcuts. And I though I practiced a lot.
So that's the first thing - don't expect too much from playing for a couple of years on on and off basis. You probably are doing really well considering the time invested. And it is actually great that you are dissatisfied and understand your shortfalls - that's the only way to get better and trust me - many people fail on the self-reflection front and don't progress.
If the improvisations or riffs you are coming up with are not satisfying the only way is to look for existing improvisations and riffs that you actually like and really invest time to learn them 100% or at least pick the elements you really like. Then you might start that though process of what is it about that riff or solo that I really like and learn how to do more of "this thing" and making it more personal.
There is one universal thing that always gets kind of bypassed in guitar education - the ear training. The more precisely you are able to hear things the more material you are able to ingest. You should strive to play riffs and solos from recordings literally on hearing them. This is the biggest superpower you can develop and a way of creating a connection between muscle memory and things that you hear in your head. Music theory works best when it is a knowledge built on top of well developed ear. Do you know a scale if you cannot sing it in your head? Do you know about harmony if you cannot identify a progression from recording on hearing it? These are the important questions I still ask myself after many many years on that journey

The mention of riffs that ‘sound like garbage’ and playing that always sounds the same suggests a different approach to this question. I’m going to assume a blues/rock/folk context where alternate tunings are quite popular and riffs are a big thing.
Once we are reasonably comfortable with basic chords and one or two scales there is an enormous amount of material that we can play. Learning more riffs or licks or chord progressions is always a good thing, but it does not automatically overcome frustrations with progress or how we sound or how well we can improvise. Right at the start I’d like to say that if we only know 3 or 4 chords and the basic ornaments from the relevant scale (2nd, 4th, 6th and ♭7th notes) then it’s possible to sound amazing. Learning more theory or more fancy figures, riffs and chords might be useful in getting into different genres such as jazz but it’s all optional. It is also unlikely to be much use if our playing sounds ordinary. The most complex, fast and difficult pieces played without mistakes can sound, well, very ordinary. There are good examples on the web of guitarists whose athletic prowess greatly exceeds their musicality, at least in my opinion. And there is nothing wrong with always sounding the same if you sound really good! B. B. King always sounds pretty much the same - and remarkably similar to T-Bone Walker in one of his moods - but I never get tired of hearing him or his fairly predicable improvisations.
I’ll reinterpret the word understanding. The important part of mastering and enjoying the guitar is not theoretical understanding if another kind of ‘understanding’ is missing. This other understanding is making the instrument part of your body and being able to make it sound beautiful, or making it sound just as you want it to sound. There is an important ‘secret’ about the guitar: just like the harpsichord it is a stringed instrument on which the strings are plucked (or picked). If you’ve tried to use sampled guitars for MIDI in a DAW, you might have noticed how bad they sound even if the samples are good. In fact they tend to sound like a harpsichord. So the secret is that while loudness and timing and note choice are the start of music on both instruments, the guitarist has infinitely more control over what happens while each note is sounding and how it is struck. That’s what makes the guitar such a challenging instrument to play really well.
Don’t bother with theory if you want to come up with great sounding and memorable riffs. These are often very simple figures. The best thing to do is to learn to love just playing around on the guitar making each note sound superb. You’ll need a critical ear and the perseverance to master the basic techniques such as legato playing, pinched harmonics, bends and vibrato, hammer ons and pull offs, all that stuff that makes a simple riff great. Timing is crucial, so getting into practice with different rhythms and individual note dynamics is also high on the agenda.
Scales can help a bit in coming up with new riffs but Elmore James made a living out of just one amazing riff with only 2 or 3 notes and he was a guitar hero for some incredibly accomplished players. In many of his songs the first note repeats over and over to build tension, which is then finally relieved with a couple of notes in the next bar. It’s a good idea to study the riffs you like to see what makes them tick. Very often repetition of notes with a distinct groove is the best start. Robby Krieger knew that: Roadhouse Blues starts with the same note played six times with a strong swing, and then a triplet. It’s the energy in the groove that makes it great. Lots of riffs start with 2 notes played with a strong pulse and if you start that way and follow them with just about anything else you’ll have a dozen new riffs before lunch. If any of them are good it will not be the notes you chose but the timing you used and the way you played each note or chord or chord fragment.
There is a very nice lesson on how to play the Money for Nothing riff in the May 2024 issue of Total Guitar magazine. Studying this kind of material and recording yourself to check whether you are improving - together with lots of practice - is the best way to get better. You should also notice that the start of that riff has a remarkable resemblance to the start of the Jumping Jack Flash riff and there is no shame in borrowing that start in making your own.
Improvisation and alternate tunings require more discussion but the free play I suggested will help with both. Finally, getting a good teacher who can tell you exactly what is causing dissatisfaction with the instrument is always a good idea. You might have to make the choice between working harder on the guitar or choosing a different instrument to play. I’d strongly advise not to give up on playing music, because it has wonderful benefits for both our physical and mental health. As Keith Richards said recently, everyone should have a guitar, it’s so relaxing to play it. I think what he meant was not any stressful, goal oriented drive to get better quickly, but just having fun noodling and feeling comfortable holding that piece of wood close and making musical sounds with it.

So I think you're asking two different questions here:
The first, is the question you put in the title - which is about mastering and deeply understanding the instrument. Most of the answers above, I think, cater to that question.
The second question, though, sounds more about staying interesting and producing fun sounds on the guitar. So I'll try to address the gap and answer that question.
The most important thing to know here is that your (and most people's!) growth as a guitar music critic has been (and will be!) much faster than your growth as a musician. It's about, as a rule of thumb, 10x faster to understand and appreciate advanced music, relative to being able to produce anything at the same level. So, to choose a number, assuming you have 5 years of listening to guitar music - that lets you appreciate and criticize music that will take you 50 years of training in order to produce....
The challenge here is in making original music, after 5 years of practice,  that will sound interesting to your years, after 5 years of music critique training. Several options:

First, lower your expectations. Amazing progress on 5 years of guitar training is still 45 years short of 50 years of practice.
Second, cheat. Learn advanced solos and improvisations, and just try re-gluing them together. How complicated and interesting can you make your rendition of the "Happy Birthday" song, by shoe-horning in licks from more complicated solos?
Third, don't do it alone. Play with anyone / everyone, especially making sure to include people who are less good than you are, and who are super enthusiastic about the music
Fourth, teach. Mastery requires boring but careful repeated review of the basics, and there's nothing that will motivate you to do that more than having to explain the basics, over and over again, to novices
Fifth, alternate challenging yourself (work hard at picking up hard things, either in your genres our far outside of them) with taking it super easy (go over your most well known repertoire)
Sixth, rearrange the same favourite songs. Take a song you know well, and figure out how to include new techniques and embellishments into it. Add extra arpegios. Modulate the key. Retune the guitar in the middle of the song. Try using a looper. etc...
Seventh, regularly try other creative endeavours. Take a movement impro class. Go to avant garde theatre. Find things that are hard for you to understand or appreciate, and make a hard hard effort to understand them. Get your mind out of its comfort zone, then take that back to the guitar

And, most of all, never ever stop playing. Play every day, even a little bit. And be patient

This speaks to a lack of understanding of music theory.
Let me be clear. Musicians often confuse the learning of music theory with the need to learn to read sheet music.
And for most self-taught guitar players, most of whom will never become a session cat,  there seems to be a smug satisfaction that we can play live and in bands, and perform all these great songs without reading a note.
Then, over the years, it begins to dawn on us;
We have learned music theory anyway.
By trial and error.
Practical experience.
Figuring out what sounds 'right', and why, intuitively, this chord structure has a pleasing feel and progression to it.
And that chord progression and those notes over there just sound wrong.
Even by modern jazz standards.
And in the end, the sheet music serves a very specific purpose, for those who either need it to perform, or those session players who want to show up to the studio, deliver the goods, and get paid.
In my opinion, you would benefit from studying music theory, and intervals, the circle of fifths, quarter notes, triplets, eight beats to the bar, and scales.
Is learning to read sheet music necessary for you to progress happily?
I offer that is it NOT. You can have one without the other.
Though I have studied sheet music, and understand what all those black symbols on the staff there mean, It's nothing I will ever need to use and put into practice.
I'm just too slow in the deciphering of it, and there's no point in really ever learning it correctly.  Not at my age. I'm a bar band musician, not a session player.
For you?
Get online.
Study guitar theory videos.
Watch Rick Beato.
Paul Gilbert.
Expand your mind out of the small box and out into the big playground.
And have fun with it!!

What is this ONE specific purpose of sheet music? If music is a language than sheet music is just an attempt at writing it down. Of course you can be a functional illiterate, you can speak, perform, memorize, improvise and even develop an intuition for idioms and grammar. The advantage of sheet music is that you can store, transmit, explain, compress, share and so on without having to be present in person, in recording or with your instrument. It's a standardized language for musicians to communicate with each other.

haxor789,
I wrote, "And in the end, the sheet music serves a very specific purpose, for those who either need it to perform, or those session players who want to show up to the studio, deliver the goods, and get paid."
In essence, I offered up not one, but two specific purposes of sheet music for the person asking the question.  He being a self-taught guitar player with no knowledge of music theory.

Studio cats need to know how to read sheet music, and know it really well.
If they want to keep getting studio gigs, and getting paid.
and,
People who aren't gifted with a natural, intuitive ear, and require sheet music  in order to perform at all.

My older brother falls into that category.
He was trained the proper way when he learned to play piano, admittedly late in life.
But when my younger brother and I, who have boatloads of natural ear, tell him, "It's a blues jam, 12-bar, in G, C, and D, go!"
He is unable.
If it isn't on the sheet music, he can't play it.
It's the darndest thing too.
Three siblings.
Two of them wired one way, and the other wired a completely different way.

I would never presume to demean or denigrate those who were raised and trained properly.
But the original poster is a self-taught guitar player.
I posted what I posted to enlighten him to a number of avenues for his advancement, I think.

I mean in it's most basic form sheet music is essentially the analog version of MIDI, it's telling an instrument (or in that case it's player) when to produce which sound and for how long. The more advanced ones will also add information about loudness, techniques, accents and whatnot to make it sound less robotic and more like music. But there's not much theory to reading that, it's essentially a more universal version of TAB. You don't even have to know what you're playing you just need to produce the right sounds at the right time. Though going through the motion is training.

So technically you can separate the two jobs of performer and composer, where the former just needs to be able to produce the sounds written down, while the latter has to develop, understand and/or apply a theory about the effects that playing or not playing certain notes/harmonies has. They nonetheless can do that using sheet music and can technically write down music that they themselves aren't able to perform. Though you probably can't really avoid making some music to compose or developing some understanding how it works to or while performing it.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I think your main issue is lack of musical vocabulary. You can make sounds and even "speak" in a way, but it feels meaningless. Music, and playing guitar, is a language and you learn it the same way you learn to use spoken languages: by repeating things you hear. Play tunes by ear on your guitar: chords, melodies, rhythms. When you play other people's chords and melodies by ear, you get more musical "words" in your vocabulary, and little by little, you start to feel like you're saying meaningful things on the guitar.

Short answer, as there are already plenty - this likely overlaps with others, but might help.

start dealing with music theory, bit by bit. What is a scale? what is a triad? what is a major/minor/7 chord? Etcetera. Take it slow, step by step, this is hard going for some people, but ultimately very very helpful, some would say essential. (Tons of info online about these topics.)

start relating the chords and licks you know to what you pick up in 1 above.

1 and 2 are not to be carried out sequentially - rather, alternate between them, and iterate towards a real understanding of the fretboard and how the treasures it holds relate to that thing we call "music".


Hope that helps.
